# post multiple Json Objects inside array to php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Well i have tried a lot ways, and i keep getting the same error. I have this Json String:

```
[{"cart":{"itemid":"2","itemAmount":"2"}},{"cart":{"itemid":"3","itemAmount":"1"}}]
```

I pass it to php with this:

```
$.post(
    "order/process.php",
    { finalOrderItems: myJsonString},
    function(data){
        console.log("response - "+ data);
    }
);
```

A simple function for testing.

But the response is get is this an NULL

Oh yeah for now i only have this on server side:

```
$finalOrderItems = json_decode($_POST["finalOrderItems"]);
var_dump($finalOrderItems);
```

Any help? thanks

Comment: but i tried json_encode for fun, and the string is being pass.. of course was the wrong format.

Comment: and i've validated the json

Comment: Do a var_dump($_POST["finalOrderItems"]) and see what you get.

Comment: It looks like you're expecting `finalOrderItems` to be a query param, yet I think you're passing this in the HTTP body. I could be wrong, since I haven't used jquery/php for years.

Comment: i get an string:
[{\"cart\":{\"itemid\":\"2\",\"itemAmount\":\"2\"}},{\"cart\": .....

Comment: open developer tools (usually f12) and view the network traffic (console tab in ff and network in ie/chrome). From there you can see everything that was posted and the response directly. Make sure the object you are expecting is being sent.

Comment: It looks like you have magic quotes on, turn it off and then try it again.

Comment: really! thanks mate, i dont know why i didnt think about that before lol :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case.. this save it:

```
php_value magic_quotes 0
php_flag magic_quotes off
php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
```

Thanks @Musa for the help

Answer (score 0):

It WILL help you. Use ajax, it's better.
Edit: If you string is a var in value of key in array 'data', replace the quotables, and put the just a var. Example: `data: {'finalOrderItems': myJsonString}`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                // GET or POST
                type: 'GET', 
                url: "json.php",
                data: { 'finalOrderItems': 'myJsonString'},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data.length) {
                        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var dataX = data[i];
                            console.log('itemid: ' + dataX.cart.itemid[0] + ' - amount: ' + dataX.cart.itemAmount[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```